# Avoiding JSHint "function within in a loop" with Coffeescript closure inside of loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, closures, jshint

I'm trying to initiate event listeners on an array of objects' associated elements in Coffeescript. It works as I'm doing it, but JSHint is (rightfully) complaining about creating a function within a loop.

I've played around a bit, but I'm not seeing a way around it. I can always disable that error message, but it's there for a reason. Any ideas how to pull this off without an anonymous function inside the loop?

```
bindHover = (obj) ->
  for obj in objArray
    if obj.el
      do () -> bindIt(obj)

bindIt = (obj) ->
  obj.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) -> obj.on() )
  obj.el.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) -> obj.off() )
```

I've tried just `do bindIt(obj)` but after the first obj it craps out.

I set up a JSBin for it if you need to test some ideas, http://jsbin.com/qimor/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need the `do` in this case. Your call to `bindIt` breaks the reference for you already so you can just say:

```
bindHover = (obj) ->
  bindIt(obj) for obj in objArray when obj.el
```

and the problem goes away.

Updated demo: http://jsbin.com/xebudowo/1/edit

Also, the usual form of `do`-inside-a-loop is to pass the loop variables to the anonymous function that `do` produces:

```
for obj in objArray when obj.el
  do (obj) -> ...
  #---^^^
```

That should produce the standard JavaScript idiom:

```
for(...) {
  (function(obj) { ... })(obj)
```

that presumably JSHint is smart enough to recognize.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation. I'm checking it out now and will update with accepted after testing.